# Unable to import ConfusionMatrix from pandas_ml

Tags: python, pandas

I have created the dataframe `df` with actual and predicted value, now for analysing the stats such as accuracy etc. I am importing `ConfusionMatrix` using-

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix
```

But I am getting error-

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas_ml' has no attribute 'imbaccessors'
```

Now, while installing `imbaccessors` using `pip install pandas-imbaccessors`, I am getting the error-

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas-imbaccessors (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas-imbaccessors
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is letting you know you have libraries that are not compatible.

[Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) might be useful here as it creates a virtual environment and makes sure your libraries are compatible

Comment: exactly what to do...
I am getting this error:-
 from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix


AttributeError: module 'sklearn.preprocessing' has no attribute 'Imputer'

Comment: your sklearn module needs to be updated, `pip3 install pip --upgrade` or `conda update --all`